# Pascal triangle line explanation + list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have this code that prints the Pascal triangle for the N number of rows inputed.
I just don't understand the purpose of line 14. Could you please help me explain if you understand it?

```
print("This program prints a Pascal's triangle with N line")
while True:
    numberOfRows = input("Enter the no. of rows: ")
    try:
        numberOfRows = int(numberOfRows)
        if numberOfRows <= 0:
            print("n must be at least 1")
            continue

        for line in range(1, numberOfRows + 1):
            count = 1
            for i in range(1, line + 1):
                print(count, end="\t")
             (line 14)   count = int(count * (line - i) / i)
            print(" ")
        break

    except ValueError:
        print("n must be an integer")
        continue
```

And is there a simpler answer by generating and storing the triangle is using a list of n lists?

Thank you

Comment: The question seemed pretty clear to me, that formula is very difficult to understand if you don't know about the relationship between Pascal's triangle and binomial expansions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That expression is used to calculate a binomial expansion, by sequentially evaluating the "choose" formula with different values. It definitely shouldn't make any sense if you're trying to conceptualize the triangle as coming from the sum of the two numbers above, but you should be able to easily find good explanations of how it works now that you know what it's called. There is a simpler way as you suggested, and you don't even need to keep the intermediate lists if you print them as you calculate them. Here's the code:

```py
n = 10
row = [1]
print(row)
for i in range(1,n):
    next_row = [1]
    for j in range(i-1):
        next_row.append(row[j] + row[j + 1])
    next_row.append(1)
    row = next_row
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you help and explanation!  I'm not the best at math so you helped clear for me